# Tic-Tac-Toe check win function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

so i am making a tic tac toe program and the check win functions dont work, it seems as it just skips through it even if its true

this is a new way i wrote and it doesnt work

```
row_1 = board[0] == board[1] == board[2] != "-"
row_2 = board[3] == board[4] == board[5] != "-"
row_3 = board[6] == board[7] == board[8] != "-"

if row_1 or row_2 or row_3:
    if row_1 or row_2 or row_3 == char:
        status = True
        check = True
    elif row_1 or row_2 or row_3 == ai_char:
        status2 = True
        check = False
```

this is the old way i had it doesnt work

```
if board[0] == board[3] == board[6] == char:
    status = True
    check = True
if board[1] == board[4] == board[7] == char:
    status = True
    check = True
if board[2] == board[5] == board[8] == char:
    status = True
    check = True

if board[0] == board[3] == board[6] == ai_char:
    status2 = True
    check = False
if board[1] == board[4] == board[7] == ai_char:
    status2 = True
    check = False
if board[2] == board[5] == board[8] == ai_char:
    status2 = True
    check = False
```

both ways looks like it should work but it doesnt

this is the whole code https://pastebin.com/G7Stkk79

Answer (score 2):

why don't you make it much simpler by using this as an option.

```
row1 = all(board[i] != '-' for i in [0,3,6])
```

You can also try to use

```
row1 = all(board[i] != '-' for i in range(0,7,3))
```

The above code will work as follows:

```
if board[0] != '-' and board[3] != '-' and board[6] != '-': 
    row1 = True
else:
    row1 = False
```

In this case, if any of the values in `board[0]`, `board[3]`, `board[6]` is equal to `'-'`, then it will result in `False` else `True`.

In your code, you are checking for an entire row. It is much easier as you are going from 0 through 8 where row1=(0,1,2), row2=(3,4,5), and row3=(6,7,8)

If you want to check if the values in each row is not '-', then this code will work:

```
row_1_dash = all(board[i] != '-' for i in range(0,3))
row_2_dash = all(board[i] != '-' for i in range(3,6))
row_3_dash = all(board[i] != '-' for i in range(6,9))
```

If you want to check if each value in a row is the same, then you can check as follows:

```
row_1_same = all(board[i] == board[i+1] for i in range(0,2))
row_2_same = all(board[i] == board[i+1] for i in range(3,5))
row_3_same = all(board[i] == board[i+1] for i in range(6,8))
```

You can also check if the values are the same and also not equal to '-' using this:

```
row_1_win = all(board[i] == board[i+1] and board[i] != '-' for i in range(0,2))
row_2_win = all(board[i] == board[i+1] and board[i] != '-' for i in range(3,5))
row_3_win = all(board[i] == board[i+1] and board[i] != '-' for i in range(6,8))
```

With these options, you can probably reduce your code to find if the player won.

Let me know if you want to know the full implementation. This may help you look at options to implement your solution.

Comment: If the problem has been addressed, you may want to read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.